# Is it possible to create an array of XYChart.Series on JavaFX?

Tags: arrays, javafx, charts, javafx-8, series

I want to know if I can create an array of `XYChart.Series<String, Number>` on JavaFX?

Because I need to create a `XYChart.Series` for each person on database, and I tried to make an array of `XYChart.Series<String, Number>` for my `LineChart` but I couldn't.

This is what I tried:

```
List<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> seriesList = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>>();
```

Because I had no idea how to do it otherways.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Chart takes an `ObservableList` of series data for it's `setData()` method, so you could have had `ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> seriesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` then `chart.setData(seriesList);` or you can call `chart.getData().add(mySeries);` for each as you are building it/them, which uses the default collection in the new chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a array of the raw type and assign it to a variable declared with a generic type.

```
int size = ...
XYChart.Series<String, Number>[] seriesArray = new XYChart.Series[size];
```

**Update**

Array elements still need to be initialized this way since arrays generated this way are filled with `null` elements.

Java 8 provides a way create & initilize a array using short code via streams API:

```
XYChart.Series<String, Number>[] seriesArray = Stream.<XYChart.Series<String, Number>>generate(XYChart.Series::new).limit(size).toArray(XYChart.Series[]::new);
```

Comment: Thank you :), but why it gives me NullPointerException here: 
seriesArray[i].setName("emri ");

Comment: @ErtanHasani Arrays are filled with `null` elements, if they are created using `Type[size]`. You still need to assign instances to the array's elements.

Comment: i added this line first series[i] = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>(); and now i got Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljavafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series; cannot be cast to javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series

Comment: Not sure how exactly you managed to create produce this exception, but `[Ljavafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series;` is a array of `javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series` so somwhere you attempt to assign such an array to a `javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series` target type.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had something else on my code that made that comes out. Found that out . Thank you so much.